# How do I make a single WordPress installation seem to power two sites?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'd like to set up a single WordPress installation at `siteA.com` with 2 static pages and a blog. I have two domain names and I would like to set it up so that `siteA.com` shows page 1 as its home page, and `siteB.com` would show page 2 as the homepage. **Both sites would share the blog contents.**

Since the Wordpress installation resides at site A, how can I create a seamless experience for the user who visits site B?

Say they type in `http://siteB.com/`. What should I do to show page 1 at this address? PHP include? Redirect? Mess with `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of Wordpress' RSS feeds to show the blog posts of site A on site B.

However, from a SEO point of view having the same content on two sites might not be a good idea (duplicate content: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359).

Answer (score 0):

Install them on two servers and use 1 database.

Answer (score 0):

Is [Wordpress MU](http://mu.wordpress.org/) what you're looking for? It's now in the full release and can be found here http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Answer (score 0):

Tricky, but probably doable, though I'm not sure why you'd want to do it this way, to be honest. You'll need to modify each WordPress install to use some different tables for different things, i.e. site info (base URL, etc.). Note that at runtime you can also use the HTTP_HOST header to determine which "site" you're displaying things for, but I suspect noodling with the tables will get you most of what you want.

See http://wordpress.org/support/topic/share-certain-parts-of-a-wp-database-over-2-domains for some more info.